# Mongo-graphql: query for two integer fields order by both fields and returns two rows if both fields have values

Tags: mongodb

I have a document with entry_height, exit_height (might be null).
Height is a bitcoin thing (block height). Several entries can have the same entry_height or exit_height.
I want to show a list where there is a row for entry_height and, if exit_height is filled, also show a 2nd row.

I need to order by height of both fields.
Let's say I have these entries:

```
1) entry_height: 1, exit_height: 5, entry_data, exit_data, ...
2) entry_height: 2, exit_height: 3, entry_data, exit_data, ...
3) entry_height: 4, exit_height: null, entry_data, null
```

The query result would be:

```
1) height: 1, entry related data...
2) height: 2, entry related data...
3) height: 3, exit related data ...
4) height: 4, entry related data...
5) height: 5, exit related data...
```

What indices should be set and how to read the data from the database?

Thanks.

update: after some reading I think that entry_height and exit_height should be a unique array field, say, height: [1, 5], [2, 3], [4].
That way I'd set up a multikey index. But I'm not sure how to know if a value comes from the 1st height entry or the seond.
Regarding the query I think the only option is the aggregate framework.
What do you say?

Comment: When you say "order by time of both fields" what does that mean?
Also:  If the doc always has entry and optional exit then ... just pull the doc and process on the client side?   Not sure what value agg can add here.

Comment: I meant order by height of both fields. I mean that  entry_height and exit_height (if present) must be taken as two collections instead of one.A single record produces two items in the resulting list on the client.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to do the trick:

```
var r = [
         {_id:0, "entry_height":1, "exit_height":5, "entry_data":"entry_DAT1", "exit_data":"exit_DAT1"},
         {_id:1, "entry_height":2, "exit_height":3, "entry_data":"entry_DAT2", "exit_data":"exit_DAT2"},
         {_id:2, "entry_height":4, "entry_data":"entry_DAT3"}
         ];

db.foo.insert(r);

c = db.foo.aggregate([
// The Juice!  "Array-ify" the doc and assign height and payload to common field names (h and d):
{$project: {x:[ {h:"$entry_height",d:"$entry_data",t:"ENTRY"}, {h:"$exit_height",d:"$exit_data",t:"EXIT"} ] }}

// The unwind creates 2 docs (in this case) for each input item
,{$unwind: "$x"}

// Toss out those items with no exit height (like _id = 2 above):
,{$match: {"x.h": {$exists: true} }}

// Finally:  The sort you seek:
,{$sort: {"x.h":1}}
]);

{ "_id" : 0, "x" : { "h" : 1, "d" : "entry_DAT1", "t" : "ENTRY" } }
{ "_id" : 1, "x" : { "h" : 2, "d" : "entry_DAT2", "t" : "ENTRY" } }
{ "_id" : 1, "x" : { "h" : 3, "d" : "exit_DAT2", "t" : "EXIT" } }
{ "_id" : 2, "x" : { "h" : 4, "d" : "entry_DAT3", "t" : "ENTRY" } }
{ "_id" : 0, "x" : { "h" : 5, "d" : "exit_DAT1", "t" : "EXIT" } }
```

The heights are in order and you can use the `t` field to figure out if the `d` field is entry or exit data.  If you have other ways of sniffing into the data then perhaps you do not need the `t` field.

With respect to indexing, not sure what you want to index to reduce the lookup space at the top of the aggregation pipeline.

Comment: Don't be shy to give it a +1.

Comment: Please tell me how to give it a +1. I can't find the option (my account is quite limited maybe that's why I don't see it)

Comment: Click the grey up arrow above the 0 in the answer